# Plug Computer Case USB 2 socket into mobo USB 3

Tags: motherboard, adapter, usb-3, usb-2

I've got an [Antec Fusion Remote Black Media PC case](http://www.antec.com/product.php?id=1203) at home. The case needs two internal 9 pin USB headers to be fully functional - one for the USB ports on the front, and one for the LCD display.

I've recently had to replace the MOBO, and I'm now using a [Gigabyte GA-A75M-D2H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3930#ov), which has one internal USB3/2 (20 pin) header, and one USB2/1 (9 pin) header.

If I understand correctly:

- The 9 pin header should be able to support two USB devices - but it didn't come with an adapter plug to do so
- I should be able to use the USB3 port, however I don't have a 9 pin male to 20 pin female adapter (i.e. to plug between the motherboard and the case)

Can anyone tell me what I need to buy to get this to work? I'm sure that eBay must have something to help me out here but darned if I can find it. The best I can find is a USB expansion board (e.g. [something like this](http://www.nzxt.com/new/products/case_accessories/iu01_usb_expansion)) but that seems like overkill.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes, there are tons of [9-pin female to 20-pin male](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-2-0-9Pin-9P-Housing-male-TO-Motherboard-USB-3-0-20pin-Female-cable-adaptor-/221064902930?pt=UK_Computing_CablesConnectors_RL&hash=item33787eb912) (to plug USB3 case into USB2 motherboard and use it as USB2), but I gather you need the opposite: 9-pin male to 20-pin female.

Though you might get lucky! This tom's hardware [post](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/327244-30-internal-connector-device-9pin) links to [this adapter](http://www.idealo.co.uk/compare/3687944/inline-usb-3-0-to-2-0-adaptor-cable-internal-usb-3-0-mainboard-to-2x-usb-2-0-device-0-15m-33446i.html) which I think is what you need. At least you've got a model to look for or ask your local shops if they could order one.

Edit: Alternatively, you could use an internal [to external usb2 adapter](http://www.akasa.com.tw/update.php?tpl=product/product.detail.tpl&no=181&type=Cables&type_sub=USB%20Cables&model=EXUSBIE-40) and plug it to your outside USB ports or to your USB3 header with [something like this](http://www.cclonline.com/product/73180/AK-CBUB09-15BK/USB-Firewire-Cables/Akasa-USB3-Internal-Motherboard-Adapter-/CAB1737/).

Comment: Yes! That is precisely the cable I need, thanks! Now, why on earth is shipping to Australia twice the cost of the cable?!